# how to update fields of campaign using id which i got as method argument with json new value?

Tags: apex, lightning, json

I have the following JSON -

```
{"FieldHistoryTracking":[{"OldValue":"2018-12-28","ObjectName":"Campaign","NewValue":"2018-12-29","FieldName":"startdate","FieldLabel":"Start Date"},{"OldValue":"2018-12-31 00:00:00","ObjectName":"Campaign","NewValue":"2018-12-30 00:00:00","FieldName":"enddate","FieldLabel":"End Date"}]}
```

After converting this JSON into wrapper using JSON2Apex I got the following wrapper -

```
public class FieldHistoryTracking {
    public String OldValue;
    public String ObjectName;
    public String NewValue;
    public String FieldName;
    public String FieldLabel;
}
```

I am trying to update Campaign record using the wrapper values but not sure how can I do it. Here is the code which I have tried.

```
public static void getcampaignchanges(string parentIds,String localfiled){
        system.debug('localfiled'+localfiled);
        system.debug('parentIds'+parentIds);
        List<Campaign> campaignList = new  List<Campaign>();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> schemaFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.fields.getMap();//Get the schema field map to get all Campaign the fields 
        set<String> allCampaignFieldList = new set<String>();
        allCampaignFieldList.addAll(schemaFieldMap.keySet());
        JSON2Apex json2Apex = JSON2Apex.parse(localfiled);
         for( JSON2Apex.FieldHistoryTracking j2xAtt :  json2Apex.FieldHistoryTracking){
                        system.debug('-------'+j2xAtt);
                        for(string fieldName: allCampaignFieldList){
                            if(j2xAtt.FieldName == fieldName){
                               // feildvalue=j2xAtt.NewValue;
                             }
                        }
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you can use the following code. You want to update the campaign record based on the values in JSON string.

The wrapper class has both the properties fieldName and newValue so you can use them.

You need to create a campaign object instance and assign the Id passed in the method parameter and then dynamically update the record values.

```
public static void getcampaignchanges(string parentIds,String localfiled){
    system.debug('localfiled'+localfiled);
    system.debug('parentIds'+parentIds);

    JSON2Apex json2Apex = JSON2Apex.parse(localfiled);

    Campaign cmp = new Campaign(Id = parentIds); //Campagin instance

    for( JSON2Apex.FieldHistoryTracking j2xAtt :  json2Apex.FieldHistoryTracking){
        system.debug('-------'+j2xAtt);
        cmp.put(j2xAtt.FieldName, j2xAtt.NewValue);
     }

     update cmp;
}
```

Let me know if it serves your purpose.

Comment: May I know the reason for down-vote? :( I tried to give the solution which would work as per my understanding.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is a code dump that doesn't provide any explanation whatsoever for the user or the community. I'd be happy to undo that if you wouldn't mind showing *how* this is an answer, although the question itself is poorly defined.

Comment: Actually  i have to update a particular records old value with new value in json  whose id must be parentid

Comment: @priyan - Can you please provide the JSON which you wants to use while updating the fields?

Comment: @DavidReed - Thanks for pointing my mistake. I will update my answer.

Comment: i'm parsing my json using a class     JSON2Apex json2Apex = JSON2Apex.parse(localfiled);

Comment: @priyan I just want the raw JSON just like I provided at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: localfiled{"FieldHistoryTracking":[{"OldValue":"2018-12-28","ObjectName":"Campaign","NewValue":"2018-12-29","FieldName":"startdate","FieldLabel":"Start Date"},{"OldValue":"2018-12-31 00:00:00","ObjectName":"Campaign","NewValue":"2018-12-30 00:00:00","FieldName":"enddate","FieldLabel":"End Date"}]}

Comment: hope u understand i have to update parentid reltaed campagin record with new value in localfiled string

Comment: @priyan Did you try the above solution? Do you want to update all the child records of the parent campaign record with the same values?

Comment: i have a ligntning cation button on click im calling controller where i get record id as parentid whose feilds need to be updated with new value

Comment: I think the above solution will work for you.